# Microsoft Graph API message is missing some properties

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

I am retrieving some messages from a mail folder "sentItems" using the Microsoft Graph API. In this message I get the "sender" and "from" properties with the data of the user that sent the email. However, there are some messages that do not have those properties. This is unexpected as the message comes from the "sentItems" folder.

I expected the properties to be consistent for all messages, but that isn't the case.

I couldn't find any reason in the other properties that could explain this. Where can I find more information about this?

Comment: Do you see the sender-related properties for these messages in MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Answer (score 1):

> I expected the properties to be consistent for all messages, but that isn't the case.

Any Outlook item can be moved or saved to the `Sent Items` folder. That is a regular folder in Outlook which may contain different kind of items as well as composed ones. Just make sure that on the client side (Outlook) you get the same results to verify that is not a Graph issue.